# Interpret case control study statistic result

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, interpretation, case-control-study

In unmatched case control study, calculating odds ratios, CI and chi-squared values and found out the statistically significant variables.  In next step performing multiple logistic regression some of the non significant variables were significant (possibly due to confounding?).  How do I have to interpret the result?

```
Serum sampling for disease on farm  OR 0.25  adjusted OR 18.1   CI 1.8- 177.2
                                    b 2.9   S.E. 1.16
```

Comment: This often happens. It is a mistake to believe that the individual and unadjusted tests are superior in some way to the multiple logistic regression tests.